# mongodb update the last array element

Tags: mongodb

the following documents:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5d648b0d5aeada5177bb54e4"),
    "time": [{
            "start": "2019/8/25 9:59:30",
            "end": "2019/8/25 10:59:30"
        },
        {
            "start": "2019/8/26 9:59:30",
            "end": "2019/8/26 10:59:30"
        },
        {
            "start": "2019/8/27 9:59:30",
            "end": "2019/8/26 9:59:30"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to update the last element in array?

I'm already tried:

```
db.document.update(
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5d648b0d5aeada5177bb54e4")
  }, 
  {
    $set: {
        "time.-1.end": "2019/8/26 10:59:30"
    }
  }
)
```

but it does not work...

Comment: Has my suggestion helped? Do let me know, I can add it as an answer maybe? Or find some other solution other than using JS in MongoDB, which should be evaded as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

it is very simple. get the last element's index/position.

```
var data = {
"_id" : "5d648b0d5aeada5177bb54e4",
"time" : [ 
    {
        "start" : "2019/8/25 9:59:30",
        "end" : "2019/8/25 10:59:30"
    }, 
    {
        "start" : "2019/8/26 9:59:30",
        "end" : "2019/8/26 10:59:30"
    }, 
    {
        "start" : "2019/8/27 9:59:30",
        "end" : "2019/8/26 9:59:30"
    }
]
}

var len = data.time.length - 1;
var objUpdate = {};
var updateQuery = "time." + len + ".end";
objUpdate[updateQuery] = "2019/8/26 11:59:30";

db.getCollection('test').update({"_id" : ObjectId("5d648b0d5aeada5177bb54e4")}, {$set:objUpdate});
```

Comment: What if there are many data inside the Array?  Should count the index first?

Comment: If you always want to update the last element of the array, better sort the array field in descending order and then use the positional operator '$' to update the first matching document

Comment: Is it efficient? I'm going to update this frequently

Comment: It'll be efficient, if you build multi-key index on the array field. That would make the sort operation quick

Comment: @glowwormX doing this will have race conditions, the data change between select, index parse & eventual update call will break it. Though not possible to do what you want with current raw mongo as well, can't you always keep the `time` array sorted in reverse order? So always update the `0th` index? When you push a new element, push to the start, rather than to the end?

Comment: @buræquete That's good idea,but how to push the first element? I did not find a method after reading the document.

Comment: @glowwormX check [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/#up._S_position), you can input ‘$position’ with value ‘0’ inside ‘$push’ command

Answer (score 1):

Filter out the document using `time.start` field:

Try the below query:

```
db.arraytest.updateOne({"_id" : ObjectId("5d648b0d5aeada5177bb54e4"), "time.start" : "2019/8/27 9:59:30"},
{$set: { "time.$.end": "2019/8/26 10:59:30" }})
```

Comment: Sometimes the value of the field is unknown