# Updating a nested array object in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a StudentClass collection that looks like this:

```
[
{
  "_id": ObjectId("60923c997b4d3205009a981a"),
  "attended": [
    {
      "in": "2021-05-05T06:35:05.226+00:00",
      "out": "2021-05-05T06:45:05.226+00:00"
    },
    {
      "in": "2021-05-05T06:47:05.226+00:00",
      "out": "2021-05-05T06:55:05.226+00:00"
    },
    {
      "in": "2021-05-05T06:56:05.226+00:00"
    },
    {
      "in": "2021-03-03T07:10:00.628Z"
    }
  ],
  "studentId": ObjectId("608a42e8224c549ad9a9ab51"),
  "active": true
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6098f6f974af29682772fbe6"),
  "attended": [
    {
      "in": "2021-05-05T06:35:05.226+00:00",
      "out": "2021-05-05T06:55:05.226+00:00"
    },
    {
      "in": "2021-05-05T06:59:05.226+00:00",
      "out": "2021-05-05T07:20:05.226+00:00"
    }
  ],
  "studentId": ObjectId("608a42e8224c549ad9a9ab51"),
  "active": true
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6098f6f974af29682772fbe7"),
  "attended": [],
  "studentId": ObjectId("608a42e8224c549ad9a9ab51"),
  "active": true
}]
```

For a give _id, I need to update the **attended** array as per the following conditions:
Need to find the **last** array element with a missing **out** key. That array element of the **attended** should get updated with the **out** key just like other array elements.

This is what I've tried:

```
const markStudentExitFromClass = (studentClassId, exitTime) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        StudentClasses.updateOne(
            { _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(studentClassId), "attended.out" : {$exists: false}}, 
            { $set: { "attended.$.out": new Date(exitTime) } }, 
            function (err, updatedData) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(updatedData);
                }
            }
        )
    })
}
```

This is not updating any array element of **attended** array for the give _id. Just like **$** positional operator finds the first array element, is there anything for the last array element?

What am I doing wrong?

Updated:
So, I got the update part working by changing the match clause of updateOne to:

```
const markStudentExitFromClass = (studentClassId, exitTime) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        StudentClasses.updateOne(
            { _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(studentClassId), "attended" :{"$elemMatch":{"out":{$exists: false}}} }, 
            { $set: { "attended.$.out": new Date(exitTime) } }, 
            function (err, updatedData) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(updatedData);
                }
            }
        )
    })
}
```

But, I still cant figure out how to get the last matching element of the **attended** array instead of the first. Any pointers?

Comment: what if `"attended": [],` is empty as per your last document?

Comment: there is another method that updates the In time before this method is being called. So, whenever this method is being called, we can assume that "attended" is not empty.

Comment: see similar question [mongodb update the last array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57668919/mongodb-update-the-last-array-element), i don't think any better way to do this single query.